# xsl accessing top level nodes

Tags: xslt, variables

I have a question on how to access the nodes from the XML using XSL.

I have a xml like this:

```
<Table>
<Row>
   <Cell Type="Main" Id="980">Test22</Cell>
   <Cell Type="SubElement">Test22 Sub Element1</Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
   <Cell Type="Main" Id="123">Test</Cell>
   <Cell/>
</Row>
<Row>
   <Cell Type="SubElement">Test Sub Element1</Cell>
   <Cell Type="Element">xyz</Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
   <Cell Type="SubElement">Test Sub Element2</Cell>
   <Cell Type="Element">abc</Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
   <Cell Type="Main" Id="456">Test1</Cell>
   <Cell/>
</Row>
<Row>
   <Cell Type="SubElement">Test1 Sub Element1</Cell>
   <Cell Type="Element">awe</Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
   <Cell Type="SubElement">Test1 Sub Element2</Cell>
   <Cell Type="Element">scd</Cell>
</Row>
</Table>
```

Now, I need to get the 1st Row's Id (i.e. Cell[Type='Main']/@Id) from the 2nd & 3rd Row's Element Cell (1st row is the parent row for 2nd & 3rd row).
Similarly I need to access 4th Row's Id (i.e. Cell[Type='Main']/@Id) from the 5th & 6th Row
(4th row is the parent row for 5th & 6th row).

I tried using xsl:variables but I couldn't assign values dynamically.

Please advise. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following expression within a template that is processing a `SubElement` or `Element`:

```
../preceding-sibling::Row[Cell/@Type='Main'][1]/Cell/@Id
```

For example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="Cell[@Type[.='SubElement' or .='Element']]">
        [<xsl:value-of select="concat(., '; Parent ID: ',
                ../preceding-sibling::Row[Cell/@Type='Main'][1]/Cell/@Id)"/>]
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Cell"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Outputs (spaces removed):

```
[Test Sub Element1; Parent ID: 123]
[xyz; Parent ID: 123]
[Test Sub Element2; Parent ID: 123]
[abc; Parent ID: 123]
[Test1 Sub Element1; Parent ID: 456]
[awe; Parent ID: 456]
[Test1 Sub Element2; Parent ID: 456]
[scd; Parent ID: 456]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... This works for the structure I mentioned here but I forgot to mention one more condition. In some cases, there wont be any sub-elements. I updated the structure now please see the first Row.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
<xsl:template match="Table">
  <xsl:foreach select="Row[Cell/@Type='Main']">
    Id: <xsl:value-of select="Cell[@Type='Main']/@Id" />
    Element 1: <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Row[Cell/@Type='Element'][1]" />
    Element 2: <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Row[Cell/@Type='Element'][2]" />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: But I need to proceed Row/cell by Row/cell not all at once. At that time how I know the Cell[@Type='Main']/@Id ?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your comment. My code goes through the "Main" rows one by one and looks for the matching two "Element" rows; so why do you write "not all at once"?

Comment: Right now, I am not looping through the table but I am parsing Cell one by one. Ok let me try this and see whether it suits our requirement